# New activity on List Click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a list. Now when I click on the list item I want to run a Java class which is another list of names.

Here is my code:

```
public class SecondAct extends ListActivity {
   private String[] items = { "Pending Retailers", "Ordered Retailers",
         "No Order Retailers", "Today's Plan", "Messages", "Daily Sales",
         "Pending Invoices", "Day Close", "Tools and Updates", "Exit" };

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
      // Get the activity's ListView and set its choice mode as multiple choice
      getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
      setListAdapter(adapter);
   }

   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      String selectionValue = "";
      selectionValue = (String) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);

      Log.i("List Selection Value: ",
            (String) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position));

      if (selectionValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending Retailers")) {

         Intent intent = new Intent("my.com.npi.List");
         startActivity(intent);
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondAct.this)
               .create();
         alertDialog.setTitle("Pending Retailers Selected");

         alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               // here we i add functions

            }
         });

         // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
         alertDialog.show();
      }

      else if (selectionValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
         finish();
      }
   }
}
```

Now when I click on the first item, the application is forcefully closed. I used intent to start the new activity but it isn't working. Hopelessly stuck! Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: yes i am attaching the logcat: 05-11 15:33:30.518: W/dalvikvm(2242): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-11 15:33:30.538: E/AndroidRuntime(2242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 15:33:30.538: E/AndroidRuntime(2242): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=my.com.npi.List }
05-11 15:33:30.538: E/AndroidRuntime(2242):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
05-11 15:33:30.538: E/AndroidRuntime(2242):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)

Comment: SecondAct is your that activity in which onListItemClick listener is present..

Comment: yes second act is the main activity.

Comment: i dont understand this :  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=my.com.npi.List }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Activity in your own Application then use:

```
Intent electIntent = new Intent();
electIntent.setClass(SecondAct.this, List.class);
startActivity(electIntent);
```

and in AndroidManifest

```
<activity
   android:name = ".List" />
```

use this intent for starting another app Activity from your appliction:

```
Intent intent25 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("APP_PACKAGE_NAME",
"APP_PACKAGE_NAME.TestActivity").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("APP_PACKAGE_NAME",
"APP_PACKAGE_NAME.TestActivity"));
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent25);
```

Comment: <application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"        android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondAct"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>

    </application>

Comment: you have two activity in your AndroidManifest first:SplashActivity and second SecondAct so which one you want to start on listitem click?

Comment: @irksome : can you tell me name of activity which you want to start then i will edit your code

Comment: splash activity is just for the splash screen. so it will run first. then the secondact activity will run which displays the list. now when i click on the list item, i want another class i.e List.java which is another activity, to run.

Answer (score 1):

First Register The New Activity in Manifest as

Before the application tag in manifest declare package like

```
<package name="my.com.npi">

<activity android:name = ".List" />
```

then 
give Correct Correct Class name in the Intent.don't use like my.com.npi
just import those package give the plain name as List.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,List.class);
         startActivity(intent);
```